# the measurements of Noah's arc and the arc of the covenent

Tags: shiurim-measurements, pentateuch-chumash

The volume of Noah's Ark is 450,000 cubic cubits. The volume of the Ark of the Covenant is 5.625. Noah's Ark was thus exactly 80,000 times larger than the Ark of the Covenant. Is it significant that the volume of one is exactly a clean integer larger than the other?

Comment: I do not understand the question. What do you want to know? Noah was given the exact measurements of the box, but it was obvious that it was only usable by miracles to begin with.

Comment: It may be a matter of the relative width length and height ratios, which would of course make the volume ratio an integer. Since the individual values are such that the sizes would of course be a multiplication, then of course the volumes would be an integer ratio.

Comment: Definitely the answer to "_sh'monim alafim, mi yodeya_?".

Comment: @sabbahillel Noahs' Ark was 300 x 30 x 50, Moses's Ark was 2.5 x 1.5 x 1.5. They are not similar.

Comment: @Clint Eastwood That is part of the point. The measurements of the ark are so much more than the Ark that of course, the volume ratio is some integer number greater. I do not see the point of the question.

Comment: Not only is it an integer number, but it is a nice clean multiple of 10 integer number.